# SSL for Subdomain of a Wildcard Subdomain

Tags: ssl, wildcard

My app needs to support company-based domain name, such as `acme.domain.tld`. Moreover, it would also have several services running such as `login.acme.domain.tld`, `account.acme.domain.tld` (to maintain same-origin COOKIE policy).

It is generally known that it's not possible to setup SSL cert for `*.*.domain.tld`. Is it possible to setup SSL cert for specific domain like `login.*.domain.tld`?

Comment: No. You’re supposed to request an SSL certificate for each service, eg. *.acme.domain.tld , *.other.domain.tld and so on.